# Why does leaflet R doesn´t show picture uploaded? also with custom icons

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I´m struggling to crear custom icons and inserting in my popups pictures (in this project tree type pictures) in order to show once the popup is clicked. In my atribute table of the data, i have created a text column named "foto" and inserted the local url of the pictures i want to upload: Ej : C:/my/work/directory/pinar.PNG

Of course i have stored my pictures in that carpet and set my WD also in that space. either wap my result is a empty picture in my popup as showned. The only thing is showned is a logotpe of a picture as it is empty.

Please how can i solve this error.

P.D. Also I have tried uploading custom icons from local and from web-url as the examples proveded by leaflet and also it doesn,t work.

Thanks.

```
library(leaflet)


mapa2 <- leaflet(data = capa) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(data = prueba,
             popup = paste(
               "<u><strong>Arbolado parque XXXX:</strong></u><br>",
               "<br><strong>Tipo:</strong> ", prueba$Tipo,
               "<br><strong>Foto:</strong><br><img src='", prueba$Foto, "' width='200'>"
             )) %>%
  addMarkers(
    label = ~TIPOLOGÍA,
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
    popup = ~paste(
      "<strong>Identificador:</strong> ", ID,
      "<br><strong>Distrito:</strong> ", DISTRITO,
      "<br><strong>Tipo de vegetación:</strong> ", TIPOLOGÍA
    )
  )

mapa2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahfga.png)

Comment: You will have to upload your image files to someplace where HTTP can find them; my suggestion is Dropbox. For a more detailed answer consider this conversation on the Posit Forum: https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-different-pictures-to-each-markers-in-the-leaflet-package-map-application/128689